# How can I remove characters from a string after the nth occurrence from the back of the string?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

So I have some strings in this format:

```
ABC_1-23_42_4242
A_D_123_A_C_6-23_4342_2345
A_B_C_1-23_4235422_24523
A_WQERQWERB_C_1-23_48972_9792
A234234_BRWER_23423_@34234_C_5-22343_48778_4784345
```

I'm only using one string at a time, so I don't have to deal with a list or multiple lines, but basically the only part that matters is **from the end of the string** everything **after** the 3rd `_`.

Desired output:

```
1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```

The dash is usually consistent but it is not trust worthy.  The best thing I could find is the 3rd `_` from the end of the string.

**Edit:** Doesn't necessarily have to use sed or awk, but those seemed like what I should be using.

Comment: Yes output.  Sorry will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `grep` for that:

```
grep -Eo '([^_]+_){2}[^_]+$' file
```

Options:

- -E enables *extended POSIX regular expressions* which simplifies things
- -o outputs only the match, not the whole line as per default

Regex:

- `([^_]+_){2}` matches a sequence of non `_` characters followed by a `_` - two times
- `[^_]+` matches the remaining characters after the last `_`
- `$` anchors the previous pattern to the end of the line

Output:

```
1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I sat for a while on http://regexr.com/ trying to figure out what I can do but I am too new with regular expressions to figure out how that first part worked..

Comment: You are welcome. You'll need some patience. Learning regular expressions takes a while. Keep on playing around!

Comment: Its mainly when trying to search in reverse thats a problem I think.  I knew about the $ being the end and I've gotten some things to work like that but the `{2}` is somewhat new to me and I wasn't sure about it and the part before..I've literally only been working with regex for about 3 days straight now, and before that was a few years ago in college.  So this is helpful for the future as well

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do this easily using field separator as `_`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} NF>2{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file

1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}` sets input (FS) and output (OFS) field separators as `_`
- `NF` is # of fields
- `$(NF-2)` is last-2 field
- `$(NF-1)` is last-1 field
- `$NF` is last field

Comment: Works only as long as `NF>=3`.

Comment: Can you explain the FS and OFS part?  awk is very new to me. (also NF >.>)

Comment: I've added some explanation in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much.  makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU or OSX sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*_(([^_]+_){2}[^_]+)$/\1/' file
1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```

Comment: While it was my first intention as well, imo this is a useless use of `sed`. Funny thing: Now there is a sed answer from Mr. awk(!) and I still complain... :)

Comment: Uh! Actually you earned 2K in the `sed` tag! Wow! Never knew that

Comment: I'm allergic to the new GNU grep options that try to make grep do things that sed, awk, and find already do very well. The GNU guys seem to be trying to turn grep into a does-everything tool which is about as un-UNIXy as you can get. They'll give grep options to sort it's output next! Yes, I've been using sed for 34 years, considerably longer than I've been using awk, so I've got a pretty good grasp of sed, including what it should be used for and what it shouldn't ;-)!

Comment: Cool! While any version of `egrep` should work with my answer I see your point. But let me admit that in my daily work I really, really like `grep -r`. That makes things much easier for me.

Comment: Unfortunately `-o` is not a POSIX option (see [the POSIX standard for grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) so your answer will only work with GNU grep (maybe **some** others?). Nothing wrong with that, just pointing it out since you mentioned it'd work in all egreps.  AFAIK `-E` for sed in my solution is GNU and OSX only too.

Comment: Shame on me. I didn't expected that because it's kind of a basic feature in my grep knowledge. But wouldn't you say that it is helpful?

Comment: No because it's easily done in other tools and the knowledge you gain in learning to do it with those other tools can be expanded upon to solve more complicated problems later whereas learning to do it in grep is a dead end at best but more often puts you on a path to shell loops and all sorts of other conjurations because you think `grep -o/r` is the right starting point. We're constantly seeing questions like "I used grep -r to find files named bob, now how do I enhance it to find files created before last Thursday....?" and the right answer is you should have used `find` in the first place.

Comment: Actually that's a great argumentation! I never thought about it like that!

Comment: But let me add that shell scripts and interactive usage are a bit different. I mean I have to execute `grep`, `sed`, `awk` tons a time every day. Things like `grep -r`, or `awk -i`, `sort -u` (and so on) are imo really helpful. (while the latter appeared limited in usefulness for me, but still sometimes good to have)

Answer (score 0):

A way that could be used that is probably not too efficient could be to count how many `_` there are then search for where the (n-2)th `_` is then print whatever is after that location like for example in your first one
ABC_1-23_42_4242
use count function to count how many `_` there are then search for the (n-2) and since there are 3 `_` n = 3 thus (n -2) = 1. So then search where the first `_` is which is located at "3" counting from 0,1,2,3 then print everything from after the 3 so 4 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

here is another approach

```
$ rev file | cut -d_ -f1-3 | rev

1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F C_ '{print $2}' file

1-23_42_4242
6-23_4342_2345
1-23_4235422_24523
1-23_48972_9792
5-22343_48778_4784345
```